# How AWS role works between two ports?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

In a private subnet, We have an EC2(client) talking to server(another EC2) listening on a port.

client EC2 is assigned a role to get access to server EC2. Client and server are GOLang programs.

AWS role is **mainly** used to perform communication with AWS API calls between any two services(AWS) without specifying the credentials.

---

Does AWS role also help in client-server communication? to authenticate right client..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly, no. You don't use IAM to control access between your client and your server. You use it to control access between your client and AWS services. IAM authenticates clients and authorizes them to perform specific actions against specific AWS resources.

One option that *would* allow your client to leverage IAM roles for authentication to your server's API would be to insert API Gateway between them. Another option is to use standard auth mechanisms such as bearer tokens, API request signing etc.

Note that, typically, you would use Security Groups to control which EC2 instances can actually talk to the server API on port N.

Comment: When you say: "between your client and AWS services", Can Java backend(DB client) talk to Amazon RDS without JDBC credentials? by assigning role to java backend server...

Comment: You can use IAM to authenticate to RDS (MySQL and PostgreSQL). See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html

Comment: So, by using IAM, doesn't java backend need parameter store with JDBC credentials? to access RDS and have JDBC connection...

Comment: No, assuming that you're using an RDS DB engine that supports IAM authentication. You get an authentication token from RDS and use that as the password. Example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.Java.html